# Any way in flot to share 0 line between two y axes?

Tags: flot, axes

I need two y axes for my flot chart.  I'd like for them to share the 0 line.  Each has a different scale.  Also, the zero line won't always be the min for both axes (sometimes one of the axes needs to start at -1 eg).  Any way to achieve this?

Comment: I can't see how this would work unless they share a scale...